# Python IF/Else syntax not working

Tags: python

I am facing problem in if/else condition.

my code and error was as following

```
>>> y=50
>>> if y<0:
    y=0
    print('Negative not acceptable.')
    elif y==0:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please suggest me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.
**Saroware Mahmud**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have indentation problem. Please look at this code:

```
y=50
if y<0:
    y=0
    print('Negative not acceptable.')
elif y==0:
    print("this is y==0 block")
```